# JQuery ajax get returns null

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using this function to populate my table in visual studio 2010. but success function returns null. in my web service i am using

Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listMsg));

```
// THIS IS MY JAVA SCRIPT CODE   

    function getAllMessages() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "TestService.asmx/GetAllMessages",
            dataType: "json",
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                var messageTable = $("#messages tbody");
                $(data).each(function (index, msg) {
                    var apnString = "<tr><td>" + msg.ID + "</td><td>" + msg.Email + "</td><td>" + msg.Message + "</td><td>" + msg.TimeStamp + "</td></tr>";
                    messageTable.append(apnString);
                });

            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

### }

here is my webMethod code. The webservice is returning json data.

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class TestService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        SQLHelper clSQLHelper = new SQLHelper();

        [WebMethod]
        public void GetAllMessages()
        {
            List<Messages> listMsg = new List<Messages>();
            DataTable dtMsg = clSQLHelper.PGSQLExecuteReader("get_all_messages", new List<NpgsqlParameter>(), "Messages");
            if (dtMsg != null && dtMsg.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (DataRow dr in dtMsg.Rows)
                {
                    Messages Msg = new Messages();
                    Msg.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["auto_id"]);
                    Msg.Email = dr["email_id"].ToString();
                    Msg.Message = dr["message"].ToString();
                    Msg.TimeStamp = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["created_on"], new CultureInfo("en-IN"));
                    listMsg.Add(Msg);
                }

                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listMsg));
            }
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSs4y.jpg)

Comment: Please let me know what is the code for web method? How is the set up?

Comment: @MaheshB please see the code

Comment: What response code do you get? What do you see in the network tab in dev tools?

Comment: @Robert just [0ms]

Comment: When you debug is hitting the break point for the web method? If not can you add the below line on top of the method and try - [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]

Comment: I am also thinking you need to return the response instead of writing it using  " Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listMsg));"

Comment: I think you would benefit a lot if you spent some time on learning how to use the developer tools in Chrome (or other browsers) for debugging. You can see the headers and contents of each request that goes in and out. This, combined with a server-side breakpoint,  usually makes finding the error a matter of seconds.

Comment: @MaheshB Earlier it was not hitting the break point. After adding your line it is coming to break point. But what should I do to return response? I mean Return Type and Return Value of the web method.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code you mentioned-

**1. In the web method you are using the below line so you are not returning anything to the client call in ajax.**

> Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listMsg));

*So you need to change the definition of the method to return string and return the response some thing like below-*

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Description")]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string GetAllMessages()
        {
            List<Messages> listMsg = new List<Messages>();
            DataTable dtMsg = clSQLHelper.PGSQLExecuteReader("get_all_messages", new List<NpgsqlParameter>(), "Messages");
            if (dtMsg != null && dtMsg.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (DataRow dr in dtMsg.Rows)
                {
                    Messages Msg = new Messages();
                    Msg.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["auto_id"]);
                    Msg.Email = dr["email_id"].ToString();
                    Msg.Email = dr["message"].ToString();
                    Msg.TimeStamp = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["created_on"], new CultureInfo("en-IN"));
                    listMsg.Add(Msg);
                }

            }
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return js.Serialize(listMsg);
        }
```

**2. You are not telling the ASMX web method how this method can be accessed**

*As you are calling the GET method on asmx you need to add below line on top of the web method*

> [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true,
>   ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]

***Importance of the above line -***

> This attribute is used to specify information for methods that can be
>   called from client script. The attribute lets you specify which HTTP
>   verb (GET or POST) can be used to invoke a method. It also lets you
>   specify whether the response is formatted by using either JavaScript
>   Object Notation (JSON) or XML.

Below are the details for other attrinutes -

**UseHttpGet**

> Specifies whether the method will be invoked by using the HTTP GET
>   command. The default is false.

**ResponseFormat**

> Specifies whether the response will be serialized as JSON or as XML.
>   The default is Json. The ResponseFormat property is useful to specify
>   XML as the return type when the method returns an XmlDocument or an
>   XmlElement object.

Please refer for more info on this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I did these thing but in console i am getting null. In front of web service  it shows only time [3ms] in debugger while page.aspx shows [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 7662ms].

Comment: Replace my new DataTable code line  to read from database query of it has any records it will return the result, also place a breakpoint at error call back in ajax call to see if any error you are getting

Comment: I didn't get you. On error callback i am using console.log

Comment: If you are returning from web method and if you are able to hit break point check which value your are returning. If that is valid records from the DB query then place break point in success call back and console that response. BTW I changed the code to read from DB

Comment: I am getting this in web service <string>[{"ID":48,"Email":"virendrak.22@gmail.com","Message":"hj","TimeStamp":"\/Date(1501759273648)\/"},{"ID":60,"Email":"virendrak.22@gmail.com","Message":"hi","TimeStamp":"\/Date(1528439285403)\/"}]</string>   Break point inside script tag is not working

Comment: If the web api returning the response means there should be another reasons for which you are not getting response! As mentioned by Robert in the above comments please share more details if you are able to fetch information  from crome debugger tools or any client errors

Comment: in Firefox debugger, under network tab, status of web service is in grey color not in green